# HashMap change Values Object

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a set with String and i want to create hash map with String key and Node Object value.
and this is my code

```
Set<String> cities = new HashSet<>();
Map<String, Node> allCity = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<String> c = cities.iterator();
while(c.hasNext()){
                String name = c.next();
                Node cit = new Node(name);
                allCity.put(name, cit);
            }
```

my problem is when i read first from c iterator and correctly make new object and put it to hash map but when second object was create in my hash map the previous object value was change like this

first read 
key = "New York"
Value = Node (and the value of node is New York)

second read
Key = "Los Angles"
Value = Node (and the value of node is Los Angles)
and my first read Value with New York key was change to Los Angles.

myNode class

```
public class Node{
private static String city;
private static double pathCost;
private ArrayList<Edge> neighbours;
private Node parent;

public Node(String cityName){
    city = cityName;
    neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static String getValue() {
    return city;
}
public static void setValue(String city) {
    Node.city = city;
}
public static double getPathCost() {
    return pathCost;
}
public static void setPathCost(double pathCost) {
    Node.pathCost = pathCost;
}

public static String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public static void setCity(String city) {
    Node.city = city;
}

public ArrayList<Edge> getNeighbours() {
    return neighbours;
}

public  void setNeighbours(ArrayList<Edge> neighbours) {
    this.neighbours = neighbours;
}

public void addNeighbours(Edge n){
    this.neighbours.add(n);
}

public Node getParent() {
    return parent;
}
public void setParent(Node parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return city;
}
```

}

Please help me.

Comment: **Just a side-note:** if you like to improve your code, change it this way `for (String name : cities) allCity.put(name, new Node(name));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you made the `city` (and `pathCost`) fields `static`. A static field belongs to the class, not to a specific instance of this class. Each node has a specific city, so you want to mek the city field an instance field, and not a static field.

Read the [Java tutorial about class members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `city` member in your `Node` class is `static`. This means **all** the `Node`s share the same `city`, and when one instance updates it (e.g., in the constructor), the change applies for all of them.

To resolve this issue, you could change `city` to be an **instance** member:

```
public class Node{
    private String city;
    ...
```

Comment: You might want to remove the static keyword in your snippet (since you tell him what to do in order to solve the issue) :)

Comment: @Thomas grr... apparently I was employing the copy-and-bug design pattern. Thanks!

Comment: That's the best pattern just after copy-and-pasta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without looking thoroughly there is a major mistake here:

```
private static String city;
```

`city` is node (i.e. instance) data and should not be static.

Since it is static in your case, *all* nodes share *one* value for `city`, which most probably isn't what you want. The same applies to `pathCost`.